# New object of class inside the class

Tags: java, class, object

In Java, or other OOP languages-

```
class MyClass{
  int a=5;
  MyClass b=new MyClass();

  void mymeth()
  {
  }
}
```

Here, creating an object of the class inside the class. When new object is created inside, it will create new members and class object(b here), which will again create members, objects? Won't this make a chain leading to infinite objects and variables?
Dumb query.

Comment: Step A before asking on StackOverflow is to compile the program, Step B is to run the program. Perform these two steps and the question does not need to be asked "what will this do?"

Comment: I've modified my code. Should I ask anew?

Comment: You've changed the meaning of the code now, your answers are no longer valid. Secondly, *run the program.* Don't ask us what the program will do when running it will provide the answer. Ask us when there is a real problem that has to be solved.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes.

You run into a [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) (ironic, isn't it?) if you try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It will lead to Stack Overflow Error.