# New object of class inside class's method

Tags: java, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New object of class inside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697814/new-object-of-class-inside-the-class)

In Java, or other OOP languages-

```
public class MyClass{
int a=5;
public static void main (String args[]){
MyClass b=new MyClass();
}
```

Here, creating an object of the class inside a method of class. When new object is created inside, it will create new members and class object(b here), which will again create members, objects? Won't this make a chain leading to infinite methods, objects and variables?

Comment: That was different. It's inside a method

Comment: It's actually not, it just looks almost identical to his other one. Really, it's more "not a question" given what is being asked here.

Comment: As I see it, both questions are answered by Anthony Pegram's comments in the last post.

Comment: Agreed, hence the "not a question".

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of `MyClass`, that in itself does not cause `main` to be executed again. In fact, the only methods that will execute are the constructor itself and any methods it calls. Therefore there is normally no recursive constructor calls and no stack overflow (unlike your earlier question). (Of course, you can write your constructor so that there is such a loop, if you like seeing your program crash.)

Answer (score 1):

The method has to be invoked explicitly - hence, in your case, the creation of new object is done only when it is invoked.
No chain !